# CSS3 vertical flyout menu + transitions not working in FF

Tags: html, css

I've got a vertical flyout navigation. The 2nd level `ul` block is shown by setting its opacity from 0 to 1 on the parents `li:hover;`. This works fine in IE and others, but in FF the transition effect doesn't work.

The HTML markup:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="">Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="">Item</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a title="" href="">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="" href="">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="" href="">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="" href="">Item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>                
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="">Item</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a title="" href="">Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="" href="">Item</a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="">Item</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Part from the CSS:

```
nav a{
    display: block;   
}
nav a:hover,
nav li.selected > a{
    color: #00fa30;
}
nav li:hover > a,
nav li.selected > a{
    color: #00fa30;
}
nav ul{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav > ul{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #006666;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 212px;
}
nav > ul > li{
    border-top: 2px solid #006666;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav > ul > li:hover{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 998; 
}

nav > ul > li > ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px; 
    left: 212px; 
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 2px solid #006666;
    padding: 0px 6px;
    background-color: #eae9e7;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;   
    width: 180px;  
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;        
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #006666;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;   
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li{
    line-height: 19px;      
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

[*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/D7Bm4/)

Comment: I've just updated the example to be easier to reproduce...

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the `:hover` from `ul > li:hover{` so that it becomes

```
ul > li {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 998; 
}
```

then your example provided will work. Sorry if I misinterpret this but here is my understanding. Apparently FireFox cannot properly handle whenever a parent element of a transitioning child has its positioning modified simultaneously. This is a known bug according to this link https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289.

If you absolutely need to apply frame/position modifying styles on hover to the parent element then you may need another work around via javascript, jQuery, etc, but in your example provided it didn't change anything. For proof here is a working js fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpZ2Z/2/)

Comment: Thanks! When i remove the :hover, the transition itself is working. But this leads to another problem: When several 1st level items contain 2nd level items, the 2nd level is not correctly shown for its parent. This means that a 2nd level gets closed and another parents 2nd level gets shown depending on the cursors y-position, although the cursor didn't leave the origin 2nd level ul block